# How does the Weierstrass Elliptic Function convert solutions to Elliptic Curves to algebraic form?

Tags: elliptic-curves, elliptic-functions

I've been reading up on elliptic functions and such, however I am still not completely familiar with them. On Wolfram Mathworld, it describes that the $\wp(\tau)$ can convert solutions to elliptic curves from the topological space of a torus, to algebraic form. Obviously, this sounds like a very important property of this function, but how exactly is that evident?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Wikipedia article [Weierstrass elliptic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions) is the important differential equation
$\;\wp'(z)^2=4\wp(z)^3-g_2\wp(z)-g_3\;$ which means that $\;(\wp(z),\wp'(z))\;$ is a point on the elliptic curve $\;y^2=4x^3-g_2x-g_3\;$ in Weierstrass form, and thus determines a parametrization of the curve. Because both $\wp(z)$ and $\wp'(z)$ are elliptic functions, they are doubly periodic and thus are determined by their values on the period parallelogram with boundary identified to give a topological torus.

An [Elliptic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve) can be also written as $y^2+a_1xy+a_3y=x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6.$ The important thing is that the genus of the curve is $1$ which means that the degree of the curve is $3$ or $4$.

Comment: Oh ok I see, thank you i thought it would be alot more complicated than that.

Comment: But am I correct in the assumption that that is the weierstrass form of an elliptic curve and that not all elliptic curves have such a form?

Comment: As pointet out e.g. in Silverman, The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, Ch. III §3 every elliptic curve (i.e. a curve of genus 1 with a specified basepoint O) is isomorphic to a curve given ba a Weierstrass equation.